# JSON Parsing Trouble in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I am trying to pull out an element from this JSON data and format it into another column in my pandas DataFrame.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#Import libraries
import json
import requests
from IPython.display import JSON
import pandas as pd 

#Load data
astronaut_db_url = 'https://supercluster-iadb.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/adb.json'
astronauts_db = requests.get(astronaut_db_url).json()

#Format data
df = pd.json_normalize(astronauts_db['astronauts'])

df_astro = df[['_id','astroNumber','awards','name','gender','inSpace','overallNumber','spacewalkCount','species','speciesGroup',
                'totalMinutesInSpace','totalSecondsSpacewalking','lastLaunchDate.utc']]


#Get row per award
df_awards = df_astro.explode(['awards']).reset_index(drop=True)
df_awards.head()

df_awards['awards'][0]['title']
```

I want to grab the title of the award for each astronaut in my DataFrame and create a new column with the list of awards in one cell that looks like the following:

```
Astronaut_ID    Awards
dh3405kdmnd     [First Person In Space, First Person to Cross Karman Line]
ert549fkfl3     [Crossed Karman Line, First Person on Moon]
```

My idea for tackling this problem was to:

1. Get a row for each award for every astronaut
2. Strip the JSON cells down to just the title
3. Recombine in one cell per astronaut

I am not sure how to complete step 2 of this process.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for using `awards` as a list of dictionaries and apply the function to every element of it.

```py
import json
import requests
from IPython.display import JSON
import pandas as pd

#Load data
astronaut_db_url = 'https://supercluster-iadb.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/adb.json'
astronauts_db = requests.get(astronaut_db_url).json()

#Format data
df = pd.json_normalize(astronauts_db['astronauts'])

df_astro = df[['_id','astroNumber','awards','name','gender','inSpace','overallNumber','spacewalkCount','species','speciesGroup',
                'totalMinutesInSpace','totalSecondsSpacewalking','lastLaunchDate.utc']]

#Get row per award
df_awards = df_astro[['_id', 'awards']].copy()
df_awards['awards'] = df_awards['awards'].apply(lambda awards: [award['title'] for award in awards])
df_awards.columns = ['Astronaut_ID', 'Awards']

print(df_awards.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing steps 1-2, you can pass in `record_path` and `meta` directly into `json_normalize`. Then step 3 can be done using `groupby` + `agg(list)`:

```
df_awards = pd.json_normalize(astronauts_db['astronauts'], 'awards', '_id').groupby('_id', as_index=False)['title'].agg(list)
print(df_awards.head(5))
```

Output:

```
                                    _id                                                 title  
0  0554c903-e8a6-43c5-8da8-76fb3495e93f     [First Steppe Tortoise  (Agrionemys horsfieldii)]  
1  0729eec8-ae2f-44a5-900f-08b2f491c8fe                    [Crossed Kármán Line, ISS Visitor]  
2  0ff02f81-a865-465d-97b8-cd6be84c56aa     [Crossed Kármán Line, ISS Visitor, Space Resid...  
3  157edd2d-58a0-4f47-b85d-4c6ade14a973                                 [Crossed Kármán Line]  
4  15c82ce2-10d5-45e7-848e-6df388307e1f                                 [Crossed Kármán Line]
```